# google cloud platform SSH You need to be root to perform this command

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

When I try to install something via putty SSH `yum install python-setuptools && easy_install pip`, it tells me that:

> You need to be root to perform this command

Even if I use `sudo yum install python-setuptools && easy_install pip` still get permission denied.

How can  get root user permission or how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `sudo` on the second portion of the command. Do this:

```
sudo yum install python-setuptools && sudo easy_install pip
```

The reason for this is that `&&` is part of a conditional shell expression, which executes the command after `&&` only if the first command was successful. `sudo` itself is a command/program, so, without the second `sudo`, this is just saying "if `sudo yum install python-setuptools` was successful, run `easy_install pip` (without sudo)".